Why are my async requests almost as slow as sync requests
My code sends async requests to an API but it's not really faster than my code with sync requests. Currently it sends around 50-60 requests and it takes around 1 minute. What am I doing wrong?
#gets total pages
def Page_count():
    response = requests.get('https://api.hypixel.net/v2/skyblock/auctions?page=1').json()
    total_pages = response["totalPages"]
    return total_pages

# Asynchronous function for getting a single page
async def get_page(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        page = await response.json()
        #says what page number at what time got scraped
        print("Got Page: " + str(page['page'] + 1))
        return page['auctions']
    
# Asynchronously get all pages with aiohttp
async def main(total_pages):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        # Create list of tasks (API calls)
        tasks = []
        for page_number in range(total_pages):
            url = f"https://api.hypixel.net/v2/skyblock/auctions?page={page_number}"
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_page(session, url)))
        # Then gather and return all responses as a list
        print("Requesting Pages!")
        pages_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print('arranging list')
        all_auctions = [auction for page in pages_data for auction in page]
        return all_auctions
    
        
total_pages = Page_count() #count pages
auctions = asyncio.run(main(total_pages))
print('there are ' + str(len(auctions)) + ' auctions') #prints how many auctions there are


try to add some TCP connection limiter to raise the default one and force it to have multiple connections simultaneously with connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=100) like variable

Could be that the server bandwidth is already maxed out? Or, if the JSON responses are large, then the code may be spending most of it's time in the JSON decoding. (I'd suggest profiling the code to isolate where it's spending its time).

@SamBull yeah the issue was that the json responses are that big. Thank you so much

If you want to improve that situation, I'd probably use response.read() to get the raw bytes, then do the JSON decoding yourself in a thread (maybe using asyncio.to_thread()).

You could try explicitly removing connection pool limits in the ClientSession:
async def main(total_pages):
    connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit_per_host=0)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        # Create list of tasks (API calls)
        tasks = []
        for page_number in range(total_pages):
            url = f"https://api.hypixel.net/v2/skyblock/auctions?page={page_number}"
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_page(session, url)))
        # Then gather and return all responses as a list
        print("Requesting Pages!")
        pages_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print('arranging list')
        all_auctions = [auction for page in pages_data for auction in page]
        return all_auctions

